# How I can split an array into different chunks depending on a certain number of zeros that exist in the array?

Tags: javascript

suppose that I have the following array:

```
In:[0,0,0,0,0,12,34,45,34,65,76,33,66,76,44,32,99,0,0,0,0,0,43,23,54,33,44,22,66,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I want to split the main array into several sub-array depending on a given condition, that is if there are 5 zero values in the array split the array into subarrays while discarding the zero value in the main array.

The output array should be as follows:

```
out:[[12,34,45,34,65,76,33,66,76,44,32,99],[43,23,54,33,44,22,66]]
```

How I can manage to do that in javascript? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can there be sequences of zeros shorter than 5? What happens with 6 or more zeroes?

Comment: It will be included in the output array. I'm trying to mimic the split-on-silence method used in python in javascript.

Comment: Here you go: `[0,0,0,0,0,12,34,45,34,65,76,33,66,76,44,32,99,0,0,0,0,0,43,23,54,33,44,22,66,0,0,0,0,0].join('').replaceAll('00000', ',').split(',').map(v => v.split('')).filter(v => v.length > 0).map(v1 => v1.map(v2 => Number(v2)))`

Comment: Thank you Franco, but in the real-world application, the number of consecutive zeroes in the array is much much bigger. Your answer (while sufficient) is suitable for dealing with a small array.  If you have another solution suitable for a large array please feel free to share. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a traditional for loop that keeps track of the last index no consecutive zeroes were found and the number of consecutive zeroes:

```js
const input = [0,0,0,0,0,12,34,45,34,65,76,33,66,76,44,32,99,0,0,0,0,0,43,23,54,33,44,22,66,0,0,0,0,0]

const output = [];

for (let i = 0, j = 0, c = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] === 0) c++; // another zero, add to counter
    else c = 0;              // reset counter if no zero
    
    if (c === 5) {           // 5 consecutive zeroes
        const slice = input.slice(j, i + 1 - 5); // get our slice
        if (slice.length) output.push(slice);    // only add if slice is not empty
        j = i + 1;           // store ending index at which we found this slice
        c = 0;               // reset counter
    }
}

console.log(output);
```